# difficulty with japanese character encoding in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, unicode, character-encoding

I have a wordpress installation in english but all of the content is in Japanese. I have set the charset to utf-8 in the head section of the page and all the characters display fine. However if I use the wordpress search widget to search for something in japanese, all of the characters get encoded into some wierd encoding that looks like this: %E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82 and so the search doesn't work. I have looked for about 2 hours trying ot find out what the problem is but I can't work it out. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where do the characters get encoded exactly? Where does that show up? Is the search working using GET parameters? Because those need to be encoded that way...

Comment: They must get encoded before they get put into the get variables cos the url for the results page will look something like this:
http://www.address.com/news/?s=%25E3%2581%25BE%25E3%2581%2599%25E3%2580%2582%25E6%2596%25B0%25E3%2582%25B7%25E3%2583%25A7%25E3%2583%2583%25E3%2583%2597%25E3%2581%25AFJR%25E3%2583%25BB

and in the search box all this rubbish appears also

Answer (score 0):

1 You have to know encoding of your Japanese contents.

2 Then you have to convert all of the contents to UTF-8, then put into Wordpress DB.

I guess you skipped step 1. Therefore wordpress DB has Shift-JIS or EUC Japanese contents.
But wordpress believed all contents were UTF-8.
Then Wordpress sent its search result with Charcterset=UTF-8 meta tag.